# How to overcome the error "Unable to connect to the filesystem" in Wordpress using Ubunto 16.04 and trying to utilise FTPS SSL

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ubuntu-16.04, ftps

I am running:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
NGINX 1.10.3 
ufw
PHP 7.0.22
Wordpress 4.9
```

After following the steps I outline below I am receiving the following error when I try to install a theme via FTPS (SSL), or plugin from the Wordpress Admin dashboard:

> Unable to connect to the filesystem. Please confirm your credentials.

[image]

The steps I have taken to enable FTPS SSL access for Wordpress on the server were taken from this Digital Ocean article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu

The article was written for Ubunto 14.04, but barring one problem with packages (outlined below), I was able to follow it without any problem.

## Steps Followed So Far

Create user account for Wordpress:

```
sudo adduser wp-user
```

Give the Wordpress user permission over all files from root www:

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo chown -R wp-user:wp-user /var/www/html
```

Create SSH keys for wp-user:

```
sudo su - wp-user
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

Told ssh-keygen to store the keys here: `/home/wp-user/wp_rsa`

Gave Wordpress user ownership of keys, and set www-data as group owner:

```
sudo chown wp-user:www-data /home/wp-user/wp_rsa*
sudo chmod 0640 /home/wp-user/wp_rsa*
```

Created SSH folder, set permisions, moved key into there:

```
sudo mkdir /home/wp-user/.ssh
sudo chown wp-user:wp-user /home/wp-user/.ssh/
sudo chmod 0700 /home/wp-user/.ssh/
sudo cp /home/wp-user/wp_rsa.pub /home/wp-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Set permissions on authorized keys folder:

```
sudo chown wp-user:wp-user /home/wp-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 0644 /home/wp-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Restricted login to the server:

```
sudo nano /home/wp-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
[then added] from="127.0.0.1 " [to the start of the file]
```

## Part of the guide I wasn't able to follow:

The next steps are:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php
```

I'm using php7, so instead I used:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev libssh2-1-dev libssh2-1
```

*These executed successfully.*

Finally the guide says to edit the wp-config file adding these defines at the end:

```
define('FTP_PUBKEY','/home/wp-user/wp_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY','/home/wp-user/wp_rsa');
define('FTP_USER','wp-user');
define('FTP_PASS','');
define('FTP_HOST','127.0.0.1:22');
```

Which I did. I restarted NGINX. Site loaded fine, but the above error was reported when I tried to upload a theme, using FTPS (SSL).

## Troubleshooting

1. I've have checked the `/home/wp-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` and the SSH key is in that file.
2. I have checked that port 22 is open. Netstat reports:

   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

How can I overcome this error? What might I try next to try to further troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line at the end of wp-config.php file

```
define("FS_METHOD", "direct");
```

Reload the webpage and try the installation again.

Answer (score 0):

[This was the best answer I got initially](https://silvawebdesigns.com/how-to-fix-unable-to-connect-to-the-filesystem-please-confirm-your-credentials-in-wordpress/) but it did not help to solve it completely.
I complemented  it with someone's answer from the following forum: [Wordpress asking for FTP Credentials | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/wordpress-asking-for-ftp-credentials)

Running the following commands fix it:

```sh
sudo chown username:www-data /var/www -R 
sudo chmod g+w /var/www -R
```

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It now is an answer, with the solution here instead of only linked, and credited to the source. (Might read weird to you, it just means that several reasons to delete this have been fixed.) Quite good. Thanks. You can improve even further, if you could also rouhgly outline the explanation (*not* copy all from the link if it has an explanation), just keywords on why/how this helps.